# How to create a folder structure from the output of DOS "tree" command

Tags: cmd

I have a text file which has the output of DOS command `tree /a`. It looks like this

```
    +---aset10
+---ConsoleApplication1
|   +---bin
|   |   \---Debug
|   +---obj
|   |   \---Debug
|   |       \---TempPE
|   \---Properties
\---testing folder
```

Actually, it has many folders. I truncated the output for brevity. Now, I want to create a similar folder structure in another computer. Is there any way to automate this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about :

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %x IN ( 'DIR /B /S /A:D' ) DO ECHO MKDIR "%x" >> somefile.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the tree output seems to me a bit nightmerish.

I would advise to use

```
 DIR /S | Find "Directory of" >> out.txt
```

Cut the "Directory of" part and work it in a simple for loop -> mkdir on the other machine.

Either that or command forfiles (works on win server 2003 but probably can be downloaded to XP as well)

```
Forfiles /S @path
```

Will give you all absolute paths recursively.